# "Internal data stream error." when using omxh264enc in gstreamer

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, openmax

I am currently trying to convert a live feed from a Raspberry Pi camera to H264 and store it as a mp4 video using gstreamer. Since I am using a Raspberry Pi 1, I need to use the hardware accelerated video encoding as otherwise the encoder cannot keep up.

I tried the following pipeline, which I feed manually with RGB image data:

```
appsrc name=src format=time is-live=true caps=video/x-raw,format=(string)RGB,width=640,height=480,bpp=24,depth=24,framerate=20/1 ! autovideoconvert ! queue ! omxh264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=output.mp4
```

However, it fails with the following output:

```
0:00:01.193743067  2469  0x1f5b320 WARN             autoconvert gstautoconvert.c:1048:gst_auto_convert_sink_query:<autoconvertchild> Got query allocation while no element was selected, letting through
0:00:01.205271623  2469  0x1f5b2c0 WARN             omxvideoenc gstomxvideoenc.c:2944:gst_omx_video_enc_propose_allocation:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> allocation query does not contain caps
0:00:02.109098855  2469  0x1f5b320 WARN          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:1189:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_dqbuf:<v4l2convert0:pool:src> Driver should never set v4l2_buffer.field to ANY
0:00:02.172643411  2469 0xa2703200 WARN                GST_PADS gstpad.c:4226:gst_pad_peer_query:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0:src> could not send sticky events
0:00:02.193615605  2469 0xa2703200 WARN             omxvideoenc gstomxvideoenc.c:1602:gst_omx_video_enc_loop:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:02.197108471  2469 0xa2703200 WARN             omxvideoenc gstomxvideoenc.c:1602:gst_omx_video_enc_loop:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> error: stream stopped, reason not-negotiated
0:00:02.329828367  2469  0x1f7eaa0 WARN              bufferpool gstbufferpool.c:1394:gst_buffer_pool_set_flushing:<v4l2convert0:pool:sink> can't change flushing state of inactive pool
0:00:02.333992206  2469  0x1f7eaa0 WARN              bufferpool gstbufferpool.c:1394:gst_buffer_pool_set_flushing:<v4l2convert0:pool:sink> can't change flushing state of inactive pool
```

Curiously, if I replace `omxh264enc` with the non-accelerated version `x264enc`, it works (although it falls behind after a couple of frames).

I assume that the warnings right before `Internal data stream error` might give some indication to what is actually going wrong, but I cannot make much sense out of them.

The full code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/pgr940yu, as well as the full debug output of that code here: https://pastebin.com/CLwAfxMG.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Best,
Homan

Answer (score 0):

It shows that now caps found which can be the problem with the format you have given in `appsrc`, try RGB24 or check out with a different color format and if you use OpenCV, it can also be BGR.